# How to solve TypeError: environment.teardown is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I can't test an application which was created with create-react-app.

All guides says that test is working by default, but when I try "yarn test", it requires install 'jest-cli' and after installation gives an error:

> TypeError: environment.teardown is not a function

Comment: You shouldn't need to install jest-cli yourself, it should come out of the box. Do this: delete package-lock.json, yarn.lock, node_modules, remove jest from the dependencies in package.json, then do npm install and yarn install.

Comment: @MstrQKN oooh thank you man, i could not figure it out for 2 days, very grateful to you

Comment: I'll add my comment as an answer, please confirm the answer so the question gets closed :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You shouldn't need to install jest-cli yourself. It should come out of the box.

Try the following:

1. Delete package-lock.json, yarn.lock and node_modules
2. Remove jest from the dependencies in package.json
3. Then do `npm install` or `yarn install`.

Comment: then how to test a single file? npm test?

Comment: Not really sure Weijing, but I think your answer should be here: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#running-tests

Comment: @WeijingJayLin , jest test files based on patterns to match files.
If you want to test a single file, you should specify an specific pattern for its file name. `yarn run test /specificfolder/otherspecific/file.spec.js`
If that pattern only matches one file. Then you will test only a single file. the one you want!

Comment: if you used ```create-react-app``` make sure ```"test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom"``` is your test script.

Answer (score 8):

Add a fresh version of "jest-environment-jsdom" to file "package.json".

Comment: Hello,Try to avoid comment in answer unless you have "specific detail" answer. Please use comment box below and Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post. :)

Comment: This inspired me and worked, `npm i -D jest-environment-jsdom@24`

Answer (score 2):

If you have not used `create-react-app` for the project:

- Just remove `jest, jest-cli, jest-environment-jsdom` from `package.json`.
- Delete folder *node-modules*, file *package-lock.json* and file *yarn.lock*.
- Use `npm --save i` or `yarn add` to install all of them so that each of them have same version.

This should work!

In my case I was missing the `jest-environment-jsdom` package.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it throws this error because I create my React project using `create-react-app` and install `jest`. In certain way it conflicts.

I *solve* it by removing `jest` from my project and using the `create-react-app` test script.

Answer (score 1):

After an evening of banging my head on this issue, I think I've finally resolved it. First, let me describe the problem:

I was also getting:

> TypeError: environment.teardown is not a function

Because I was trying to upgrade Jest to the latest version. When starting an app with Create-React-App, it installs an earlier version of Jest that does not include all of the features. I was interested in using the inlineSnapshots feature, which allows you to assert rendered components against HTML markup inside your test file.

There are a few things not included in the documentation of either Create-React-App or Jest which you should be aware of. If you want to use newer Jest features, like inlineSnapshots, then you need to do the following:

- yarn adds a fresh version of Jest and jest-environment-jsdom
- yarn add prettier --dev (This is to facilitate rewriting back into the source file.)
- Add a Jest env docblock to the very top of each test script.

A docblock is a JavaScript block comment with a pragma mark "@". For setting the Jest environment, you would add this to the top of every test file:

```
/**
 * @jest-environment jsdom
 */
```

This instructs jest to run the test in the jsdom environment, which should match what is passed in the test scripts section of your *package.json* file. Mine looks something like this (ignore the parts with react-app-rewired):

```
   "scripts": {
      "start": "yarn run flow && react-app-rewired start",
      "build": "yarn run flow && react-app-rewired build",
      "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom"
   }
```

After doing all of this, I was finally able to get inlineSnapshots to work.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was the module import binding. Basically, for me, it was the module export/import binding.

Basically if it was exported using `module.export`, you should import using `require`. If it was exported using `export` or `export default`, you should import using `import`.

No mixing is allowed here.

Comment: `module.export`? Not `module.exports`?