# Jest with TypeScript: TypeError: environment.teardown is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jestjs

I am getting this error when I try to run my tests with Jest:

```
 FAIL  src/__tests__/jokeGenerator.test.tsx
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: environment.teardown is not a function

      at node_modules/jest-runner/build/run_test.js:230:25
```

I came across a possible solution here: *[How to solve TypeError: environment.teardown is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50696201/how-to-solve-typeerror-environment-teardown-is-not-a-function)*

But after doing what was suggested: removing my yarn.lock file, node_modules folder, removing Jest from my package.json, and reinstalling everything again with yarn--I encountered a new problem:

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string

      at assertPath (path.js:39:11)
      at Object.relative (path.js:1173:5)
      at Object.getCacheKey (node_modules/ts-jest/dist/utils/get-cache-key.js:15:16)
```

I have a hunch that the reason the previous solution worked for others was because they used `create-react-app` and then installed a conflicting version of jest alongside it. If that is the case, then the above solution does not apply to my problem because I did not use `create-react-app`.

So I reinstalled Jest and @types/jest and now have the same initial problem...

This is my webpack configuration:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.tsx',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: __dirname + '/dist/',
  },
  module : {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'ts-loader'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          {
            loader: 'typings-for-css-modules-loader?modules?named',
            options: {
              modules: true,
              namedExport: true
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "practice-testing",
  "private": true,
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --hot",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^23.3.1",
    "@types/react": "^16.4.9",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.7",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-jest": "^23.4.2",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "css-modules": "^0.3.0",
    "jest": "^23.5.0",
    "react-testing-library": "^5.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.22.1",
    "ts-jest": "^23.1.3",
    "ts-loader": "^4.4.2",
    "typescript": "^3.0.1",
    "typings-for-css-modules-loader": "^1.7.0",
    "webpack": "^4.16.5",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
}
```

This my jest config:

```
module.exports = {
  "roots": [
    "<rootDir>/src"
  ],
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest"
  },
  "testRegex": "(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.tsx?$",
  "moduleFileExtensions": [
    "ts",
    "tsx",
    "js",
    "jsx",
    "json",
    "node"
  ],
}
```

And lastly, this is my tsconfig:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "jsx": "react",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
    },
    "include": [
        "./src/**/*",
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**TLDR**

This error often means there is a `jest-environment-jsdom` and/or `jest-environment-node` installed at the root of `node_modules` that is incompatible with the version of `Jest` being used to run the tests.

**Details**

This one was interesting.

The problem is `css-modules`.  It has a dependency on `jest@20.0.4` (that should have been under its devDependencies).

`jest@20.0.4` ends up installing `jest-environment-jsdom@20.0.3` and `jest-environment-node@20.0.3` which end up in the root of `node_modules`.

`jest@^23.5.0` is installed which installs `jest-environment-jsdom@^23.4.0` and `jest-environment-node@^23.4.0` in multiple places within `node_modules/jest`, but not at the root level of `node_modules` since the `20.0.3` versions are there.

When a [`testEnvironment`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#testenvironment-string) is specified for `Jest`, the resolve process looks for the environment.  [The first place it tries is within the project](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/b22a2328d2b7f153dff55043fd4076694f69563a/packages/jest-config/src/utils.js#L105-L142) which in this case is resolving to the `20.0.3` versions.

Those earlier versions of the test environments do not contain everything required by later versions of `Jest`, including a definition for `teardown()`.

Remove `css-modules` from `package.json`, delete your `package-lock.json` and/or `yarn.lock` and `node_modules` and run `npm install` and that should clear things up.

(Note that `css-modules` [only has 133 weekly downloads and no listed github site](https://www.npmjs.com/package/css-modules), I'm guessing it was added as a dependency by mistake, it is not associated with [CSS Modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules))

Comment: Great catch! Thank you!

Comment: You can find out which package is causing this via `cat node_modules/jest-environment-jsdom/package.json | grep _requiredBy -A3` (on linux) which will print the packages that originally required it. Thanks so much for this answer, very helpful!

Answer (score 6):

Just in case anyone else stumbles on this inside a project using yarn workspaces I resolved the same problem by [not hoisting](https://yarnpkg.com/blog/2018/02/15/nohoist/) `jest` to the project root:

```
"workspaces": {
    "packages": [
        "packages/*"
    ],
    "nohoist": [
        "**/jest/**",
        "**/jest"
    ]
},
```