# TypeError: environment.teardown is not a function error in jest after solution applied

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs

I am using Linux Mint OS. I am learning `Testing` in react.js. I created an app using `create react app`. I installed jest-cli using `sudo npm i -g jest-cli`. My folder structure is like below

[image]

My test is like below

**App.test.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

it('renders without crashing', () => {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, div);
  ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(div);
});


describe('Addition', () => {
  it('knows that 2 and 2 make 4', () => {
    expect(2 + 2).toBe(4);
  });
});
```

My package.json is like below

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "react": "^16.3.1",
    "react-bootstrap-sweetalert": "^4.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.1",
    "react-router": "^4.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.4",
    "react-smart-data-table": "^0.5.3",
    "react-table": "^6.8.2",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^0.79.1",
    "sweetalert": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:4000"
}
```

I am getting below error

[image]

I read [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50696201/how-to-solve-typeerror-environment-teardown-is-not-a-function). As per instruction of that post I did following steps

1. Delete package-lock.json and node_modules.
2. Remove jest from the dependencies in package.json (This is not present in my setup)
3. Then do npm install.

But I am still getting error.

Answer (score 1):

You don’t need to install `jest-cli`, that may be what’s causing the error. `create react app` already has jest bundled, try removing `jest-cli` from your global dependencies and running `npm test`.

Comment: Thanks @helloitsjoe. How can I remove `jest-cli` ?

Comment: Thanks @helloitsjoe. I am getting this output `foysal@laptop:~/Videos/my-app/client$ jest App.test.js
bash: /usr/bin/jest: No such file or directory`. Thanks.

Comment: I missed the part where you said you removed jest from package.json. `npm install jest` (no `-g`, no `jest-cli`)

Comment: Thanks @helloitsjoe. I am getting previous error again `foysal@laptop:~/Videos/my-app/client$ jest App.test.js
bash: /usr/bin/jest: No such file or directory
`.

Answer (score 1):

Remove all your node_modules(Delete the node modules folder). Then install them using `yarn` or `npm install`, Run your test using `npm test` or `yarn test` command.

Comment: Thanks @Thuvarakan for your reply. I am getting below error after applied your solution.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/tByGd.png